# property name collision using Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I ran into a what I think is a collision with a reserved property on the Function object ([Function.name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name)) and I'm wondering if there is a way to have a static variable called "name" on my "home" class below, all in lowercase, without conflicting with Function.name?

**raw javascript:**

```
// Note: I've changed the "home" class to "_c0" here to show the problem more clearly.
var myApi;
(function (myApi) {
    var _c0 = (function () {
        function _c0() { }
        _c0.name = "Home"; // this is colliding with the "Function.name". there is no "name" property on this object during runtime
        _c0.Name = "Home";
        _c0.name1 = "Home";
        _c0.url = "/Home";
        return _c0;
    })();
    myApi.home = _c0;
})(myApi || (myApi = {}));

console.log(myApi.home.name); // prints "_c0" <- this is the name of the function
console.log(myApi.home.Name); // prints "Home"
console.log(myApi.home.name1); // prints "Home"
console.log(myApi.home.url); // prints "/Home"

for(var prop in myApi.home)
    console.log(prop + ": " + myApi.home[prop]);
/* prints: (note the lack of "name: Home" in the output)
    Name: Home
    name1: Home
    url: /Home
*/
```

**Typescript file:**

```
module myApi {
    export class home {
        static name = "Home";
        static Name = "Home"; // just testing
        static name1 = "Home"; // just testing
        static url = "/Home";
    }
}

console.log(myApi.home.name);
console.log(myApi.home.Name);
console.log(myApi.home.name1);
console.log(myApi.home.url);
for (var prop in myApi.home)
    console.log(prop + ": " + myApi.home[prop]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there isn't a way to do that. Function objects have the `name` property and it cannot be overridden. Simple proof of that can be found in the snippet below:

```
var F = function(){}; 
Object.defineProperty(F, "name", {value: "Home"}); 
//TypeError: Cannot redefine property: name
```

What this means is that the static `name` property is readonly. A new value cannot be entered, as it is prevented by the descriptor of that value. I suggest you choose another name for your property.